# Which method name fits in best with Objective-C/Cocoa conventions?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, naming-conventions

Here's a quicky question. Which method name makes the most sense for an Objective-C Cocoa application?

```
-(void) doSomethingWithAnimation:(BOOL)animated
```

or:

```
-(void) doSomething:(BOOL)animated
```

or even:

```
-(void) doSomethingAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the Cocoa convention would give your examples the following semmantics (ignoring the BOOL type for the argument, obviously):

```
-(void) doSomethingWithAnimation:(BOOL)animated
```

would actually expect an Animation as the parameter (i.e. something that represents the animation.

```
-(void) doSomething:(BOOL)animated
```

would expect the Something to do.

```
-(void) doSomethingAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

would, as Noah answered, do something with optional animation.

Answer (score 3):

-(void)doSomethingAnimated:(BOOL)animated seems most consistent with Apple's naming style. For reference, check the iPhone UIKit docs - UINavigationController's -popToRootViewControllerAnimated: method, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option to consider: make two methods, `-doSomething` and `-doSomethingWithAnimation`.

Then, if you want, you can have them both tail-call a third, private method, and give that method any name you want. :)

Comment: This won't work so well if the animated parm is coming from elsewhere consider this:

- (void)doSomethingAnimated:(BOOL)anmimated {
    [self doSomethingElse:animated];
    [otherView doAThirdThing:animated];
}

becomes a PITA if you have 2 different methods.

Answer (score 0):

write your comment clearly and tersely for example :
//do Something with the Animation

Then write your method name based on this comment, like below
doSomethingwithAnimation:(BOOL)animated

Objective-C and Cocoa are designed to read well, so if your method cannot be a clear narrative of your code, it might not be well named.